# Time out connect to ffx component run "fuchsia-pkg://fuchsiasamples.com/hello_world#meta/hello_world.cm"

Tags: vpn, fuchsia

My system is MacOS and I have already build fuchsia, but when I run the command line

```
 fuchsia % ffx component run "fuchsia-pkg://fuchsiasamples.com/hello_world#meta/hello_world.cm" 
Timeout attempting to reach target "unspecified"
```

this error occurred.

Hmmm.. I think it is because I am in China but I've already used VPN
Is there any solutions

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

> My system is MacOS and I have already build fuchsia...

Since you mentioned you are building Fuchsia yourself, make sure any guidance you follow comes from the [Platform Source side of Fuchsia.dev](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/get-started).

> `ffx component run "fuchsia-pkg://fuchsiasamples.com/hello_world#meta/hello_world.cm"`

This looks like you might be following the [Get Started with the SDK](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/get-started/sdk) developer guide, which is not intended for developers who have the source tree and are building Fuchsia.

> Timeout attempting to reach target "unspecified"

Based on the above comments, this can happen if you are mixing versions of `ffx` between the SDK and a local source tree build (for example, in two different terminal windows that have a different `PATH` configured). So make sure all commands you run are using the same `ffx` binary.

Beyond that, this generally means that the `ffx` daemon is unable to communicate with your device or emulator instance (i.e. it doesn't appear in `ffx target list`). The most common causes are:

1. [Firewall rules](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/get-started/get_fuchsia_source#configure-firewall-rules) aren't set up correctly
2. [SSH keys on the device](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/development/sdk/ffx/create-ssh-keys-for-devices) don't match the host

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I will have a try~May be it is because I set the PATH wrong. Thanks again! Hope this can help!